# Getting the SourceCode of all the types within an Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, roslyn

I already found a similar question on stackOverflow. Still the answer was a bit disappointing since: "It doesnt work" is hard to accept. 
My problem: I wrote some Roslyn-diagnosticAnalyzers which i would like to test. To do that, I want to load an assembly and get the source code (or better: SyntaxTrees) of all the types within the assembly. Now the problem is: I cant figure out a way to get the file path (respectively the SyntaxTrees) of the types.
This is where I am stuck right now.

```
var fullName = typeof(TypeWithinAssembly).Assembly.FullName;
var assem = Assembly.Load(fullName);
foreach (var item in assem.GetTypes())
{
  item <= here i would like sth like: item.filepath or item.getText()
}
```

Is there any other way I could get the code of the types?

Comment: if you have the source files then its really easy just File.ReadAllLines() if you don't then you have to write a decompiler like ILSPY or try your luck with `Mono Cecil` or `PostSharp` or `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetMethodBody();`

Comment: in order to use File.ReadAllLines() I think i need the filepath right? but thats where Im stuck in the first place :( 
i dont know how to write a decompiler and what System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetMethodBody(); helps me.

Comment: But a compiled assembly doesn't have source code. Decompiling IL into readable C# (if the source even was C#) is not trivial. Why do you want this? Note that an assembly doesn't have source paths, that information is stored in the PDB.

Comment: Ok i see why my search is taking so long if there is no filepath. Do you know any kind of workaround for me to be able to test my diagnosticAnalyzers on the given assembly besides doing it all one by one with each file?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to analyze an already compiled binary?

Comment: to test my diagnosticAnalyzers. If it works just like the current FxCop it´s fine. If there are differences it´s not.